# Mysql innodb assertion failure

Tags: mysql, innodb

MySQL server went down automatically and i am getting the following error in log file.

```
2017-06-02T05:04:46.428891Z 1613143 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
2017-06-02T05:04:46.428891Z 1613143 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory of the same name as a data file.
2017-06-02 10:34:46 0x3b88  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 15240 in file fil0fil.cc line 896
```

kindly help anyone to clarify the issue

Comment: Are you using windows/*nix OS? The error clearly says, mysqld doesn't have enough access to write to data directories. 

On windows,  start MYSQLD as an administrator, on *nix, start with sudo user privileges.

Comment: Is there also a stack trace?  What version of MySQL Server are you running? (`mysqld --version`)

Comment: windows 8 @harshavmb

Comment: MySQL 5.7 @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: Did you try running mysqld as an administrator from command prompt???

Comment: An assertion failure *should* result in a complete stack  trace, or at least there should be more information in the error log.  It's best not to start "trying things" on a MySQL installation until the nature of the problem is clearly understood.  Is there more log information?

Comment: i couldn't run as addministrator @harshavmb

Comment: I don't think you can run `mysqld` as a non-admin user. You may have to consider databases hosted on cloud. Were you denied of admin access?

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly says, `mysqld` doesn't have enough access to write data to data directories.

On windows, start cmd prompt as an `administrator` and fire your `mysqld` process

On *nix OS, start `mysqld` process with `sudo user` privileges.